# Unicode issue in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, nltk

I saved tweets in a json file

This is my code :

```
def on_data(self, data):
    try:
        with codecs.open('python.json', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            f.write(data)
            print("Tweet ajoute au JSON")
            return True
    except BaseException as e:
        print("Error on_data: %s" % str(e))
    return True
```

but I get this type of character : `\u0e40\u0e21\u0e19\u0e0a`

I tried everything to not have this kind of character but nothing works(utf-8, latin2...)

Comment: What, exactly, is the problem?

Comment: this kind of character distort my tokenization. So i would not like to have that kind of character

Comment: No, what do you mean you get that kind of character? In *what*? Please explain the issue exactly, ideally giving us enough information to reproduce your problem. Note, it doesn't look like you've made a JSON file.

Comment: Instead of having Chinese words for example I have these characters which prevents my tokenization. I also have these characters for line breaks which are then considered as words during tokenization

Comment: {"created_at":"Wed Apr 18 08:10:56 +0000 2018","id":986517420478087168,"id_str":"986517420478087168","text":"\u0e23\u0e35+\u0e40\u0e21\u0e19\u0e0a\u0e31\u0e48\u0e19\u0e1e\u0e34\u0e21\u0e1e\u0e4c\u0e40\u0e25\u0e02\u0e2d\u0e30\u0e44\u0e23\u0e01\u0e47\u0e44\u0e14\u0e49\u0e2b\u0e49\u0e32\u0e21\u0e0 This is what i get in my json

Comment: What do you mean *you have them*?? In a file? Printing out the result to the terminal... *what **exactly** *

Comment: Well, that is a valid JSON. Have you tried deserializing it and using `print data['text']`?

Comment: https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2018/16/3/1524040502-capture-d-ecran-2018-04-18-a-11-34-06.png

Comment: Yes, that is how these unicode characters are represented in Python 2, but try `print`ing them.

Comment: Do you know that `\t` in a Python string does not actually display `\t` if you print it, but shows a (magically variable!) number of spaces instead? If you print `\n`, somehow the cursor moves to the next line? Now, extrapolate. The **internal** notation `\u0e19` somehow, magically, *prints* as "น". (If printed to a console that supports this script.)

Comment: can i save my tweet directly like that :https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2018/16/3/1524040862-capture-d-ecran-2018-04-18-a-11-40-14.png In my json file

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it merely shows a lack of understanding.

Comment: What is the content of `data` in your example?  do you know about the [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the non-ascii characters encoded directly in the JSON file, you need to encode JSON with the [`ensure_ascii=False`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#basic-usage) option.

Comment: This could be useful, if there were any indication the OP knows to use the `json` module.